# How to proceed : Show $\det A=0$ if two rows or columns are identical

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, proof-writing, determinant

$A$ is an $n \times n$ matrix. I want to show it has $\det A=0$, if two rows or columns are identical, without invoking linear dependency or the like.

I was looking at a $3\times 3$ matrix, and noticed that if the second and third columns of the matrix were identical, then each term in the sum had an additive inverse - therefore $\det A=0$. This is all according to the definition $$\det A=\sum_{b\in S_n}(-1)^Pa_{1(b)}a_{2(b)}...a_{n(b)}$$

So for an $n\times n$ matrix, we would have a sum with $n!$ terms and each pair of permutations (columns $n-1$, $n$ are identical) $b_1=(1,2,3,...n-1,n)$, $b_2=(1,2,3,...n,n-1)$ would just be equals with a different sign, since they require a different number of transpositions $P$ to construct. A difference of one, that is, and so they have opposite signs. Is it possible to construct the proof using this idea? What is the problem?

Comment: Many of the lines of the [invertible matrix theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invertible_matrix#The_invertible_matrix_theorem) give a rather immediate answer. Choose your favourite.

Comment: the IMT was one of the things which I was referring to with " or the like"-part

Comment: The idea is right. If you exchange the two columns, the sign indeed changes. But as they are undiscernible the value of the determinant doesn't change. The only option is zero.

Comment: You are correct that if two columns are the same, then you can use the permutation definition and pair each term with its additive inverse. I've posted a proof of this below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $n\ge2$, and suppose columns $i$ and $j$ are the same for some $1\le i<j\le n$.

Note that $A_n$, the group of even permutations, has two left-cosets: $A_n$ and $(ij)A_n$.

Note also, that for any $\sigma\in A_n$, if $\pi=(ij)\sigma$, then we can show that

$$a_{1,\pi_1}\cdot a_{2,\pi_2}\cdot\ldots\cdot a_{n,\pi_n}=a_{1,\sigma_1}\cdot a_{2,\sigma_2}\cdot\ldots\cdot a_{n,\sigma_n}.$$

The idea is that $\pi$ behaves just like $\sigma$ except that if $\sigma$ sends $k\mapsto i$, then $\pi$ sends $k\mapsto j$, and vice versa. But in each case the above products are the same, since columns $i$ and $j$ are the same.

Hence we have that

$$\begin{align*}
\det(A) &= \sum_{\sigma\in S_n}(-1)^{\text{sign}(\sigma)}a_{1,\sigma_1}\cdot a_{2,\sigma_2}\cdot\ldots\cdot a_{n,\sigma_n} \\
&= \sum_{\sigma\in A_n}a_{1,\sigma_1}\cdot a_{2,\sigma_2}\cdot\ldots\cdot a_{n,\sigma_n}+\underset{\sigma\in A_n}{\sum_{\pi=(ij)\sigma}}(-1)\cdot a_{1,\pi_1}\cdot a_{2,\pi_2}\cdot\ldots\cdot a_{n,\pi_n} \\
&= \sum_{\sigma\in A_n}\left(a_{1,\sigma_1}\cdot a_{2,\sigma_2}\cdot\ldots\cdot a_{n,\sigma_n}-a_{1,\sigma_1}\cdot a_{2,\sigma_2}\cdot\ldots\cdot a_{n,\sigma_n}\right)=0.\end{align*}$$

A similar proof that works when two rows are the same can be recovered from this one. Alternatively, you could use the above determinant definition to show that $\det(A^T)=\det(A)$.

Answer (score 1):

This result is in the very definition of the determinant (relative to a basis)  for a vector space $V $ of dimension $n$ with basis $\mathcal B=(e_1,e_2,\dots, e_n)$ over a field $K$: it is the $n$-linear *alternating form* on $V^n$, $f(v_1,v_2,\dots,v_n)$, which takes the value $1$ on the basis.

It can be shown that all alternating forms on $V_n$ are  scalar multiples of this form.

Alternating means precisely that if any two vectors $_i$ and $v_j$ are equal, the form takes the value $0$. What you specify as the definition of the determinant is just a consequence of being alternating and $n$-linear, thereby giving away to calculate explicitly the determinant.